# Distinguish methods from attributes in ipython tab completion

Tags: python, ipython, readline

Is it possible to configure IPython such that the tab completion allows me to visually distinguish between attributes and methods of an object? Probably the nicest way do this is by color, similar to the [fancycompleter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancycompleter) module (can this module be tied into ipython?). Another way would be to add a star or parentheses to callables.

Comment: Would be awesome, I'm looking for this myself because I can't distinguish otherwise... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the messaging protocol doesn't allow that. But there is a proposal for [completion machinery improvement](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-11%3a-Tab-Completion-System-Refactor), you can take part of the discussion and think we us of what would be necessary to implement that.

Comment: Something possible lately in newer versions?`Do you know?

Comment: messaging protocol has been extended a few weeks ago and should allow smarter things. Still the IPython team has a limited amount of volonteers so this as not moved forward. Without someone to take care of it, it will not improve before a while.

Comment: Okay thanks, very sad because this would be a really AWESOME feature, because currently, you never know which is which. But nevermind, I understand it's possible with limited contributors :(

Comment: You can alway try to work on it. Contribution are welcome and we will by happy to guide you.